# connectedComponents() and connectedComponentsWithStats() functions are undefined error Opencv 3.2.0

Tags: opencv, connected-components, undefined-function, opencv3.2

Even if I imported all Opencv header files, connectedComponents() and connectedComponentsWithStats() functions seem undefined. All other opencv functions are work fine. I use Opencv 3.2.0 with Visual Studio 2013.

[connectedComponents() function is undefined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMT80.jpg)

How can use these functions in OpenCV 3.2.0?

Comment: which includes are you using?

Comment: @api55 <opencv2/core/core.hpp>,<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>,<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>,<opencv2/opencv.hpp> or only <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: they look like the correct includes, what i think it could be is either the include directory is set wrong (but probably you should notice it) or you are including the wrong OpenCV version perhaps? you can check the latter inside your app with: `std::cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;`, but version 3.2 should have it

Comment: @api55 OMG thats my mistake,I added wrong Property Sheet to the project. So now I understand connectedComponents() function works with only opencv 3.x versions. Thank you